# Ideas for generating a class quiz from an array with 300 questions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, logic, pseudocode

I want to start off with that I don't want an answer, I just want ideas so in essence this is a collaborative brainstorming of pseudo-code or concepts :)

Problem: I was asked to write a program that generates a class quiz, this quiz needs to get questions from an array (300+-) and print them out in a random order and only x amount of them. Each quiz needs to be unique, although they may contain the same question at different times of the quiz. This quiz will be in electronic format so if some of the questions are multiple choice I will need a function of some sort that generates a table with a radio button for each choice (gets a little confusing here). I am only worried about the client-side programming now. I am going to be using JavaScript for the client-side stuff, but feel free to reference any other language.

Please feel free to add any suggestions and/or recommendations as well :)

Comment: Probably not a good idea to start off with "I don't want an answer" at StackOverflow's Q&A style site.

Comment: This is not the proper place for this question. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: I'd suggest trying to do it, and asking for help with actual problems. As I see it, brainstorming should be something done within your dev-team (or with your client).

Comment: Sorry guys I'm a newbie here, take it easy on me... @crush

Comment: @SnakeEater First thing you should do, as a `newbie` is read the rules...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like such:

```
int quizlength = 10;//number of questions to display
var QuestionNumbers;//store list of question numbers
while (questionNumbers.Length < quizlength)
{
    int randomNo = new random();//remember to set min and max values as well as a salt
    if(!QuestionNumbers.Any(x=>x == randomNo)//if the question number is not yet in the list
    {
        QuestionNumbers.Add(randomNo);
    }
}
```